# Difference between DCGAN & WGAN

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

In my understanding, DCGAN use convolution layer in both Generator and Discriminator, and WGAN adjust the loss function, optimizer, clipping and last sigmoid function. The part they control is not overlapping. So are there any conflict if i implement both changes of DCGAN & WGAN in one model?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, DCGAN proposed a well-tuned and simple model (or more specifically we can say it proposed a simple network structure with well-tuned optimizer) to generate images.WGAN proposed a new method of measuring the distance between data distribution and model distribution and theoretically solved the GAN's problem:unstable,mode collpase etc.

So you can utilize the network structure and parameters proposed in DCGAN and the way of updating parameters of discriminator and generator proposed in WGAN. And i've done that before, It's not conflict.

But in practice, you might not get a very good result when you implement WGAN.It's more advisable to implement WGAN-GP
There is an image  generated by WGAN-GP

[images generated by WGAN-GP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJUtb.jpg)

Hope my answer is helpful.